# Performance Issue after .net core 2.1 migration

Tags: performance, profiling, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-standard-2.0

Existing .Net framework 4.6.2 based web api project & class libraries have been migrated to .net core 2.1 webapi project & its class library have been migrated to .net standard 2.0 with very minimal core, mostly as part of migration either existing nuget package has been upgraded and existing package was swapped with .core compatible SDK version with very minimal/negligible code changes.
Right after the migration application's entire functionalities facing performance issue.

Once.Net framework based out code has been migrated to .net core, is the performance issue expected one?

Any effective open source tool to profile & measure performance?

Any mitigation to solve these performance issue? please suggest

Comment: try 3.1, here Microsoft made perf improvements.

Comment: You mean .net core 2.1 is having native performance issues?

Comment: no, but Microsoft improves it with every release and 3.1 is last stable version, so try it.

Comment: Some answers/suggestions about the above queries would be appreciated.

Comment: we can't answer this without any details. what is slow?

Comment: Let me know the details you need. Convert the webapi application which was running all these days on .net framework 4.6.2 to .netcore2.1 by upgrading SDKs or by swapping out required SDKs not much code changes expect 10-15 lines. Once after up gradation the existing code while running on .netcore2.1 became considerably slow. Any reasons for slowness? or guidelines or checklist to follow during .netcore2.1 conversion to overcome slowness?

Comment: this is still not enough information. what in details is slower? How did you trace/detect the slowness?

Comment: Slower was detected while doing perf. test with api request's response times. We had benchmark reading taken for all our api's response while it was running on.net framework 4.6.2 runtime. Comparing the api response time while it is running on .net framework 4.6.2 verses .netcore2.1 slowness is detected.

Comment: and how much is it slower? how many %? such kind of questions re impossible to be answered without having any details. profile both (.net framework and .net core based code) and check for diffs. try several profilers until you find anything

Comment: Around 40-50% slowness observed. Tried out VS2071 in-build diagnostics tool but the details it providing are not consistent enough. Sometime it is not providing details too. Me too looking for some suggestion on reliant profiler. Do you can any profiler recommendations? any other general suggestions specific to performance improvement on .net core? like <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection> on .csproj

Comment: try this profiler: https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/ but asking for tools is offtopic here.

Comment: tried already it make my machine very slow. Any general suggestion or points to consider  while converting .net framework webapi to  .net core2.1 ? to retain or improve performance.

Comment: sorry but there is no other way. I'm out now of this topic.